# Comparar horário atual com valores de um arquivo

Tags: python, datetime

Estou tentando pegar uma lista de horários de um arquivo (Já consegui), e agendar conforme o horário: compra programada para as 15:30, neste horário vou executar a compra (API.Buy)

```
# alimentação
sinal vem do arquivo TXT
lista = (23,5,2020,18:10,EURJPY-OTC,PUT) 
today = datetime.today()

for sinal in lista:
    dados = sinal.split(',')

    # Divide variáveis
    dados[3] = datetime.strptime(dados[3], '%H:%M').time()

    #compara horários
    if(dados[3]==today): 
        API.buy(entrada,dados[4],dados[5],5)
        #valor, moeda, direção, tempo;
      
print("Operação efetuada...")
```

Answer (score 2):

A comparação de horário que você está fazendo não vai funcionar.

Quando você faz o *parsing* de uma string que só tem a hora e o minuto (`'%H:%M'`), o segundos e frações de segundo são setados para zero. Além disso, o método [`time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) retorna um [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time), ou seja, um objeto que só contém os campos de horário, independente do dia. Ex:

```
print(datetime.strptime('18:30', '%H:%M').time()) # 18:30:00
```

Mas quando você usa [`datetime.today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today), o horário contém a hora atual, incluindo os segundos e frações de segundo:

```
print(datetime.today()) # 2020-07-27 09:28:57.649383
```

Além disso, `today` retorna também a data (dia, mês e ano). Ou seja, mesmo que as horas e minutos sejam iguais, os demais campos não serão.

Por isso, para a comparação funcionar, precisamos extrair apenas os campos de horário de `today` e setar os segundos e frações de segundo para zero, usando [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
# pega somente o horário com time(), e seta os segundos e frações de segundo para zero com replace()
today = datetime.today().time().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

for sinal in lista:
    dados = sinal.split(',')
    dados[3] = datetime.strptime(dados[3], '%H:%M').time()
    # compara horários
    if(dados[3] == today):
        # etc...
```